# How to use regular expression edit the content?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm edit an rst file for a document. There are lot of image links I have to edit them one by one, I'd like to ask, is there anybody can help write a regular expression that can transfer it in one time.

The original text looks like:

```
*Figure 1.2: Where is the dog?* <dog.html#fig_dog>
```

I'd like it translate it to:

```
:ref:fig_dog
```

---

And there is another one:

```
*How are you* <how_are_you.html>
```

I'd like it translate it to:

```
:ref:how_are_you
```

I have try some expression in editplus or notepad++, but i can't match them very well.

Comment: use a replace after the `<` and remove `.html` and anything not before or after `_` (im not sure what language you want) and obviously add `:ref:` before that text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search:

```
\*.*?\*\s*<(?:.*#)?([^.>]+)(\.[^>]*)?>
```

Replace:

```
:ref:\1
```

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, it's so magic and powerful, it saving a lot of time for me, as there are lots of files I have to edit.

Answer (score 0):

split into two regexes

To match before the html

```
<(.*).html.*?>
```

To match the anchor

```
<.*.html#(.*?)>
```